# Getting colour in preview area to display when I type into input box using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a code such that I should see the preview area change colour when I type names into the input box.  I need to call the setPreviewColour in the event handler and pass the current value of the input box into it.

Below is my code:

```
function setPreviewColor(item){
    $('.preview').css('background-color', item);
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#add-to-favorite', function() {

    setPreviewColor($('#color').val());
//  $('#items').append('<li>' + $('#color').val() + '</li>');
//  $('.preview').css('background-color', $('#color').val());


} );
```

HTML code

```
    <div id="container">
     <h1>Color picker</h1>
     <input id="color" type="text"/>
     <button id="add-to-favorite">Add to favorites</button>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="column">
         <div class="preview">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="column">
         <div id="colors">

         </div>
       </div>
       <br/>
      <div class="color-code"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Screenshot of broswer

[image]

It doesn't change when i click on the Add to favourites button. It only changes when I press CTRL+ SHIFT +J to go to the console. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you want the color to change as the user is typing or only when they click the button?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use onkeyup on a button with id (add-to-favorite), you need to attach the onkeyup event to your textbox:

```
//Change what you have to the following, now as a user types in the textbox
//with id of color, it will send the value of the textbox to setPreviewColor()
$(document).on('keyup', '#color', function() {

    setPreviewColor($('#color').val());
    //OR
    //setPreviewColor($(this).val());

} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#add-to-favorite', function() {
```

to

```
$('#add-to-favorite').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: The online tutorial wants us to use keyup instead of click. It also wants us to use the $(document). I will give it a try though